# how can php store (not display!) entire html page of returned result of search query at public database

Tags: php, php-curl

I am using php to query a public database. **Problem**:  These results would normally display in my browser.  I do not want the results to be displayed.  I need to store the html source code as a text file to filter later.  I have tried cURL and simple_html_dom.  These libraries work for the return of small amounts of data, but for the entire html page to be echo'd or saved works only intermittently, 25-percent of the time at best. My browser can grab this material with ease, unlike my simple PHP code. I will be in awe of any coding suggestion that works, but any small suggestion will also be appreciated.

Here is code that shows a query followed by storage of the resulting html page... As I mentioned, the code sometimes works. More often, it does not work.

```
$searchURL = 'https://www.example.com/search/?empty-date=1&sdate=&edate=&eventSelect=&yearSelect=&searchtype=Videos&sort=Most+Recent+Event&text=0&all%5B%5D=2020&show100=';

$pathToStorage = 'thisdate/';
$makename = $pathToStorage . "search" . $currDay . ".html";
$fp = fopen($makename, "w");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $searchURL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
fwrite($fp, $output);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);

// end of code
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please post some of the code that you've tried, so that people can help you better.

Comment: It's possible that the page source does not contain the data, and fetches it via AJAX after the page loads.

Comment: Do you know if the public database you're using has a web API? That would be preferable to scraping data from HTML.

Comment: No there does not seem to be a webAPI.  I did check a while back.

Comment: the page that loads (on my browser) would definitely be a page rendered from multiple areas of the source website. So, Don't Panic, you are saying that the page needs to render over time.  That makes sense. But I do not know how to do that programmatically with curl.  I will check that out.

Comment: Hi Howard E., I can post some code, but I really do not think it is a code bug or issue like that.  Let me see if there is something that will make it clearer.  Note that I did this a number of years ago in Perl. And it was so straightforward and easy.  So, there is something I am not grasping about the security features perhaps?

Comment: You can verify that the data is being loaded that way using the network tab of your browser dev tools. If you filter the request type to XHR you can see if any of those requests contain the data you're trying to get. No offense intended if you already know this. I don't know what anybody knows :-)

Comment: great. thanks! I will try the filter. Meantime, I have just now posted some sample code using curl.